# I try to connect to local host and glassfish server and cannot establish connection

Tags: glassfish, localhost, port

I have recently instaled glassfish-4.1. When i try to establish connection with the localhost page or to glassfish (127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.1:8080) - i get an error reply. When I checked the Netstat- an command on my cmd - I couldnt find either ports in the log. I get "Error connection refused" What should i do?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED    i type in the cmd: asadmin start-domain domain1 and it doesnt activate anything. i get the following reply:

Comment: comand start - domain failed.